# Why is Gelfond's constant transcendental?

Tags: pi, transcendental-numbers

I have seen a proof of $\pi$ being transcendental by conclude that transcendental number powered by algebraic number must be transcendental and algebraic number powered by algebraic number must be algebraic.

So, from the equation $e^{i\pi} = -1$ and $i$ is algebraic so $\pi$ must be transcendental.

But then why is $e^{\pi}$ transcendental?

Comment: For all $p$? For prime $p$? For some special $p$?

Comment: The proof is given in the first paragraph of the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond's_constant), using the exact same tools you use to conclude that $\pi$ is transcendental.

Comment: @StellaBiderman The question has been edited

Comment: Transcendental number powered by an algebraic need not be transcendental, and algebraic powered by algebraic need not be algebraic, in fact "usually" is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the **Gelfond-Schneider theorem** to prove that $e^\pi$ is transcendental. The theorem states that:

*If $a$ and $b$ are algebraic numbers with $a ≠ 0,1$ and $b$ non-rational, then any value of $a^b$ is a transcendental number.*

Using the equality:

$$
e^\pi = \left( e^{i \pi} \right)^{-i} = (-1)^{-i},
$$

we obtain $a=-1$ and $b=-i$, the latter of  which is algebraic and non-rational. Therefore $e^\pi$ is transcendental.